# Please help, i need to install openbts

Tags: 16.04, gnuradio

The internet is working fine even on ubuntu firefox, the link of google-coredumper.googlecode.com is working in ubuntu firefox but not in ubuntu

My code:

```
mranmehdi551@Muhammad-VirtualBox:—/dev$ ./build.sh N200 
- checking for a supported radio type 
- found 
- checking for a compatible build host 
• - WARNING : dev-tools is currently only tested on Ubuntu 12.04, YMMV. Please open an issue if you've used it successfully on another version of Ubuntu. 

- adding additional repo tools 
- done 

- checking build dependencies 
• - done 

- make a home for this build 
mkdir -p BUILOS/2016-10-10--22-37-20 
# libcoredumper - building Debian package and installing as dependency 
cd libcoredumper 
./build.sh 
wget http://google-coredumper.googlecode.com/files/coredumper-1.2.1.tar.gz 
--2016-10-10 22:37:20-- http://google-coredumper.googlecode.com/files/coredumper-1.2.1.tar.gz 
Resolving google-coredumper.googlecode.com (google-coredumper.googlecode.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution. wget: unable to resolve host address 'google-coredumper.googlecode.com' 
ERROR: command failed! - ERROR: command failed!
```

(code is copied from terminal Virtual Machine to Laptop, so might have errors)

Please help

How to complete ./build.sh N200 command???

Comment: DNS resolution issue from your Virtual Machine.  The DNS on your VM is either not working, is misconfigured, or your networking on your VM is just plain busted.  Can you `ping 8.8.8.8` without issues from the VM?  Can you `ping google.com` without issues?

Answer (score 0):

Manual method:
From the following link: https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-coredumper/downloads , download the coredumper-1.2.1.tar.gz and copy paste it in /dev/coredumper. It works!

OR
also try

Change the link in /dev/libcoredumper/build.sh to https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-coredumper/downloads/coredumper-1.2.1.tar.gz and then execute ./build.sh N200.